# Count the occurrence of a string in an input file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

There is a shell script which is supposed to process an incoming text file.

This text file contains strings split on multiple lines, and each string is present more than once.

The shell script needs to read this text file and output the String and count of each string.

Consider the text file is:

> Tim
>
> tim
>
> Mark
>
> MARk
>
> Allen
>
> ALLen
>
> allEN

The output should be like this:

> Tim appears 2 times
>
> Mark appears 2 times
>
> Allen appears 3 times

Right now, I am able to print the occurrence of strings, but that gets repeated the number of times the string occurs, that is "Tim appears 2 times" gets printed twice. I was trying to replace a string with NULL as soon as I count its occurrence, but for some reason, the sed is not working, coz maybe I am not invoking it at the right place (or in right way)

```
 #!/bin/bash

INPUT_FILE="$1"
declare -a LIST_CHARS

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
        echo "Usage: $0 <file_name>"
        exit 1
fi


if [ ! -f $INPUT_FILE ]
then
        echo "$INPUT_FILE does not exists. Please specify correct file name"
        exit 2
fi

while read line
do
        while read i
        do
                echo $line
                count=`grep -i $line | wc -l`
                echo "String $line appears $count times"
        done < $INPUT_FILE

done < $INPUT_FILE
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classic awk solution is something like:

```
$ awk 'NF{ count[ toupper( $0 ) ]++} 
    END{ for ( name in count ) { print name " appears " count[ name ] " times" };
}' input
```

Comment: +1, though instead of `/./` you can use `NF` that would skip blank lines just fine.

Comment: @jaypal  Good suggestion.  And that handles lines with whitespace better.  Edited.

Answer (score 13):

You can also use sort and uniq with flags to ignore case:

```
sort -f FILE | uniq -ic
```

Simple `sed` command can change the output format to the specified one:

```
s/^ *\([0-9]\+\) \(.*\)/\2 appears \1 times/
```

Comment: Great one-liner :-) `sort -f FILE | uniq -ic | sed 's/^ *\([0-9]\+\) \(.*\)/\2 appears \1 times/'`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `data.txt` contains your word Following script will do.

```
while read line
do  
    uc=$(echo $line | tr [a-z] [A-Z] | tr -d ' ')
    echo  $uc $(grep -i "$uc" strs.txt | wc -l)
done< data.txt | sort | uniq
```

Output.

```
31
ALLEN 6
MARK 4
MOKADDIM 1
SHIPLU 1
TIM 4
```

Another option is

```
sort -f data.txt | uniq -i -c  | while read num word
do  
    echo $(echo $word|tr [a-z] [A-Z])  appeard  $num times
done
```

Note: I see your text file contains blank lines. So the 31 in the output contains the number of blank lines.

Comment: This is `O(n²)` if data.txt is a copy of strs.txt

Comment: @Benoit- Yes, but I also cannot think of a way in which I can achieve the objective in a single iteration of the file.

Comment: @Benoit: My solution should be faster.

Comment: @choroba Still your solution needs iteration for printing. I have added that.

Comment: @choroba What would be your sed command? Can you elaborate your answer with the sed command too?

Comment: @Benoit Right you are. I have also added another solution. Thanks to choroba

Comment: The new solution is optimal...Thanks Shiplu

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `sort filename |uniq -c``
do
    # --if to print data as u like--
done
```